# Stretch the graph vertically

Tags: canvas, graph, stretching

Here is a [sandbox](http://jsfiddle.net/qeyqe/) (http://jsfiddle.net/qeyqe/).
Here is a beautiful [picture](http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/4286/55279410.jpg) of what I expect saying «stretch the graph vertically».

So, I have an array of dots for my graph and a canvas with 100 px height. The maximum and the minimum values of my graph are 84 (0.8425) and 44 (0.439) respectively — so, graph's height range is 40 px (84 - 44). But I need to stretch this graph so it take the whole 100 px height range — I need to transform value «84» to 100 and value «44» to 0; other intermediate values needs to be also transformed (stretched) to fit new 0-100 px range, not old 0-40 px (see picture above).

So, the main question is not how to «scale» the graph, but how to «stretch» it vertically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may stretch the value directly in your code by replacing the line

```
value = Math.round(ratesValues[i] * 100);
```

with the following lines:

```
min = 0.439;
max = 0.8425;

value = Math.round((ratesValues[i]-min)/(max-min)*100);
```

You may change the numbers `0.439` and `0.8425` to reflect the actual minimum and maximum of your graph.